# CSV upload display glitch Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord, file-upload

So I set everything up in the controller and model areas correctly, but am having some problems on the view side of things. For some reason, it is displaying correctly for 1-3 seconds but sort of "breaks character" as more elements load up and pops into what I can only describe as terminal view, or just raw array view instead of the html/css it should be in. Here's my code:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Last Funding</th>
    <th>Total Funding (USD)</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <%= @data.each do |datum| %>
    <tr>
    <th><%= datum.company_name %></th>
    <th><%= datum.country_code %></th>
    <th><%= datum.region_name %></th>
    <th><%= datum.description %></th>
    <th><%= datum.last_funding_on %></th>
    <th>$<%= datum.total_funding_usd %></th>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

here's what it looks like in-browser:

[#<Datum id: 1, country_code: "United States", region_name: "California", company_name: "Tesla", description: "Tesla Motors was started by a group of Silicon Val...", last_funding_on: "0005-09-20", total_funding_usd: 20434184632, created_at: "2020-10-25 17:42:39", updated_at: "2020-10-25 17:42:39">, #<Datum id: 2, country_code: "China", region_name: "Shanghai", company_name: "WM Motor", description: "WM Motor is an automotive company that designs, ma...", last_funding_on: nil, total_funding_usd: 3073404327, created_at: "2020-10-25 17:42:39", updated_at: "2020-10-25 17:42:39">,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
<%= @data.each do |datum| %>
```

with

```
<% @data.each do |datum| %>
```

because you do not want to output (`<%`) the return value of the `each` method call. You only want to output (`<%=`) of the attributes.

Comment: Maximum derp level achieved... congratulations to me >.< Thanks, works perfectly now haha